# Debug.Fail does not work when platform is x64 or x86

Tags: c#, .net

How can I make the `Debug.Fail` and other methods of the `Debug` class and `Trace` class work appropriately when my application compiled for x64 or x86 and not for Any CPU?

Comment: You are running in Release mode, correct?

Comment: No I am running in Debug mode for that reason I want to use Debug.Fail

Comment: Do you mean the check box on the properties page of the project under build tab (Define DEBUG constant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Project properties page in Build tab under General group check both Define DEBUG constant and TRACE constant
these options will make it functional